# homogeneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In lectures , I learned that an ODE of the form : 
$$a_n(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+a_{n-1}(x) \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+...+a_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_o(x)y=g(x) $$
 is defined to be homogeneous if $$g(x)=0$$
but when solving this ODE for example
$$x^3y'+8x^2yy'+4xy^2-y^3=0$$
we said it is homogeneous since $$f(tx,ty)=t^{3} f(x,y)$$ 
So I want to know when an ODE is said to be homogeneous ? do we have to check which condition?  $$g(x)=0\  \ \  \ \ OR\ \ \ \ \ \ f(tx,ty)=t^{k} f(x,y)$$

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html